# Where can I see how events are wired up in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, autoeventwireup

My noodle had a spark of sentience.  I was going through my ASP.NET pages, where I noticed

> Hang on, Page_Load is not equal to the name of the class, thus it cannot be the constructor of my class on my aspx.cs page

I have a gut feeling that `AutoEventWireup="true"` is responsible for telling the page to, by default, call the `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method.  The problem (and question) is that I do not know how or where I can view which events are wired up to which handlers. I am sure that `AutoEventWireup="true"` has this snippet somewhere:

```
this.Load += this.Page_Load
```

I am merely seeking to expand my knowledge on this. Where can I see which events are being "wired up" by AutoEventWireup?

**Edit**

I found the idea after trying to do a virtual constructor call (I made a constructor in my code-behind since I accidentally deleted `Page_Load`. Resharper suggested I had to seal the class. I thought that it was uncommon behavior. Double checked another page, and copy pasted my `Page_Load` back in. That's how I wonder how the events are actually wired up. How does ASP.NET know it must call `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for .NET 4 other frameworks would be slightly different but poking around with Reflector you can find that `TemplateControl` which `Page` and `UserControl` both inherit has a private method `GetDelegateInformationWithNoAssert` which wires up these delegates.

```
private void GetDelegateInformationWithNoAssert(IDictionary dictionary)
{
    if (this is Page)
    {
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_PreInit", dictionary);
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_PreLoad", dictionary);
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_LoadComplete", dictionary);
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_PreRenderComplete", dictionary);
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_InitComplete", dictionary);
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_SaveStateComplete", dictionary);
    }
    this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_Init", dictionary);
    this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_Load", dictionary);
    this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_DataBind", dictionary);
    this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_PreRender", dictionary);
    this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_Unload", dictionary);
    this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_Error", dictionary);
    if (!this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_AbortTransaction", dictionary))
    {
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("OnTransactionAbort", dictionary);
    }
    if (!this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("Page_CommitTransaction", dictionary))
    {
        this.GetDelegateInformationFromMethod("OnTransactionCommit", dictionary);
    }
}
```

If you follow the usages of this method up you will see it gets called from `HookUpAutomaticHandlers` and this method only attaches the delegates when `SupportAutoEvents` is true.

Comment: Holy crud, that's quite a lot of effort you have gone through there. And this one code section I see what I wanted to see. AutoEventWireup is very limited to which Handlers you can assign for it.

You deserve this one